# Inputext nullpointer with <p:ajax> and @ViewScoped

Tags: ajax, null, primefaces, textinput, view-scope

i'm facing a problem and i can't solve :(

By choosing an item in a selectOneRadio, i want to set a specific variable :

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{rechercheBean.choose}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Critere 1" itemValue="c1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Critere 2" itemValue="c2" />
        <p:ajax update="critere" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="critere">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{monBean.choix eq 'c1'}">
                <h:outputText value="Critere 1 :" />
                <p:inputText id="cr1" value="#{rechercheBean.critere1}" />
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="#{monBean.choix eq 'c2'}">
                <h:outputText value="Critere 2 :" />
                <p:inputText id="cr2" value="#{rechercheBean.critere2}" />
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Add critere" actionListener="#{rechercheBean.add}"/>
</h:form>
```

With the managedBean SessionScope, this code works but with the ViewScope, it doesn't works.

in ViewScope, the specific variable is null when i click on the button but if i remove the component , the specific variable is set !

I need to use  to switch between inputext :(

how can i resolve my problem ?

Tx a lot !

Comment: Can you post your backing bean code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the

```
 <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{monBean.choix eq 'c1'}">
```

with

```
<panelGroup rendered="#{monBean.choix eq 'c1'}">
```

(replace both `<c:when`)

also if you are using primefaces you can replace the `<h:commandButton` with `<p:commandButton` , or just add `f:ajax` to your current `<h:commandButton`